# System.IndexOutOfRangeException on the collection which initialized once and length not changing, how?

Tags: c#

I can not understand why I received today `System.IndexOutOfRangeException`. I've received it when program was working for 8 hours already and the place where exception occurs was executed many millions times. This place is very simple:

```
for (int i = 0; i < _goldDesiredOrdersBuy.Length; i++)
{
    _goldDesiredOrdersBuy[i] = -1;               // IndexOutOfRangeException! Strategy3.cs:line 666
}
```

I initialize _goldDesiredOrdersBuy only once when program starts so it's guaranteed that it's initialized when exception occured:

```
private int[] _goldDesiredOrdersBuy = new int[MaxOrderbookDepth];
```

I have one another place where I touch this array:

```
    private int GetGoldVolumeBuy(int bidQuotesPos)
    {
        if (_goldDesiredOrdersBuy[bidQuotesPos] > -1)
        {
            return _goldDesiredOrdersBuy[bidQuotesPos];
        }
        int result = GetGoldVolumeBuyNotCached(bidQuotesPos);
        _goldDesiredOrdersBuy[bidQuotesPos] = result;
        return result;
    }
```

And that's all. `_goldDesiredOrdersBuy` initialized once when application starts, guranteed to be initialized and length of array is not modifing anywhere, so I don't understand how I received `IndexOutOfRangeException`, any thoughts?

```
Unhandled Exception: System.AggregateException: A Task's exception(s) were not observed either by Waiting on the Task or accessing its Exception property. As a result, the unobserved exception was rethrown by the finalizer thread. --->
   System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. --->
   System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
   at MyProj.Strategies.Strategy3.CalculateNewDesiredOrdersBuy() in C:\Oleg\projects\MyProj\MyProj\Strategies\Strategy3.cs:line 666
   at MyProj.Strategies.Strategy3.RecalculateBuyOrders() in C:\Oleg\projects\MyProj\MyProj\Strategies\Strategy3.cs:line 567
   at MyProj.Strategies.Strategy3.OnAllTablesUpdated() in C:\Oleg\projects\MyProj\MyProj\Strategies\Strategy3.cs:line 499
   at MyProj.Strategies.Strategy3.AllTablesUpdated() in C:\Oleg\projects\MyProj\MyProj\Strategies\Strategy3.cs:line 413
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.<>c__DisplayClassf`1.<ForWorker>b__c()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvokeWithArg(Task childTask)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c__DisplayClass7.<ExecuteSelfReplicating>b__6(Object )
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForWorker[TLocal](Int32 fromInclusive, Int32 toExclusive, ParallelOptions parallelOptions, Action`1 body, Action`2 bodyWithState, Func`4 bodyWithLocal, Func`1 localInit, Action`1 localFinally)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEachWorker[TSource,TLocal](IEnumerable`1 source, ParallelOptions parallelOptions, Action`1 body, Action`2 bodyWithState, Action`3 bodyWithStateAndIndex, Func`4 bodyWithStateAndLocal, Func`5 bodyWithEverything, Func`1 localInit, Action`1 localFinally)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Action`1 body)
   at MyProj.Market.FinishUpdatingTables() in C:\Oleg\projects\MyProj\MyProj\Market.cs:line 449
   at Library.Exchange.Gate.DoGateIteration() in C:\Oleg\projects\MyProj\MyProj\Gate.cs:line 143
   at Library.Exchange.Gate.<Connect>b__0() in C:\Oleg\projects\MyProj\MyProj\Gate.cs:line 98
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskExceptionHolder.Finalize()
```

Answer (score 2):

From [`System.Array` on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.aspx)

> Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

By sharing this array instance among multiple threads, you are going against the documentation.  You should lock properly.

Comment: i do not share `_goldDesiredOrdersBuy` amongh multiple threads, at least i don't meant to do so. in paralellel foreach each thread has own `_goldDesiredOrdersBuy` member

Comment: well actually `_goldDesiredOrdersBuy` is accessed from different threads. But at the same time `_goldDesiredOrdersBuy` is always accessed from one thread only. i.e. every time I execute parallel foreach I have new thread likely, but I always execute new parallel foreach after previous one is finished.

Answer (score 1):

**Imo** the problem is that you have several functions that accept parameter like `int index` (or something like that) and using that parameter to recover a data from array.

The size of array is not changed, it's ok. But even if your array length is static and equal to (say) 5, if you will try to access to that array with `index>=5`, you will get the exception you described.

**EDIT**

Another possibility considering that exception is raised inside the `for(...)` loop, bounds of which are marked with the size of the array itself, I would say that considering execution stack, you execute stuff in *parallel*. So, I *suppose* that the size of array, somehow changes, at this point.

To check this, you can try to do the following:

```
int limit = _goldDesiredOrdersBuy.Length; //SET LIMIT BEFORE ITERATION
for (int i = 0; i < limit ; i++)
{
    _goldDesiredOrdersBuy[i] = -1;           
}
```

and check if the error still happens.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I initialize `_goldDesiredOrdersBuy` in one part of my program. In constructor of the class which called only at program start-up. So I don't understand how `_goldDesiredOrdersBuy` size can be changed. Probably I should just catch that exception and print more tracing information (array length, i etc.) then rethrow not to hide problems

Answer (score 0):

Well, this method doesn't check for valid indexes passed in.
So I will try to put some safety checks here.

```
private int GetGoldVolumeBuy(int bidQuotesPos) 
{ 
    int result = -1;
    if(bidQuotesPos >= 0 && bidQuotesPos < _goldDesiredOrdersBuy.Length)
    {
        if (_goldDesiredOrdersBuy[bidQuotesPos] > -1) 
        { 
            return _goldDesiredOrdersBuy[bidQuotesPos]; 
        } 
        result = GetGoldVolumeBuyNotCached(bidQuotesPos); 
        _goldDesiredOrdersBuy[bidQuotesPos] = result; 
    }
    return result; 
}
```

I am assuming that `result=-1` is a valid output here

Comment: note that exception occured in the different part of the program. in the part that very trivial.

Comment: We are facing an impossible situation. So something in the info available could be wrong. I doubt the validity of the stack trace (given also the parallel execution). I still bet on obvious places like the one above.

Comment: i see. well for now I surrounded place where exception occured to catch it and print more debug info.

Answer (score 0):

You are not checking that the value of `bidQuotesPos` lies within the range of the array.

```
private int GetGoldVolumeBuy(int bidQuotesPos) 
{ 
    if (bidQuotesPos < 0 || bidQuotesPos >= _goldDesiredOrdersBuy.Length)
    {
        // either throw an exception, or (less desireable) return a value so that the caller
        // knows that an error occurred.
        return HandleInvalidInputValue(bidQuotesPos);
    }

    if (_goldDesiredOrdersBuy[bidQuotesPos] > -1) 
    { 
        return _goldDesiredOrdersBuy[bidQuotesPos]; 
    } 
    int result = GetGoldVolumeBuyNotCached(bidQuotesPos); 
    _goldDesiredOrdersBuy[bidQuotesPos] = result; 
    return result; 
}
```

Comment: note that exception occured in the different part of the program. in the part that very trivial. While your suggestion may be useful it is not related to my question, cause it is not answer how  I received exception at Strategy3.cs:line 666